# Hide button in listview ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I want to hide a button in a list view.

The condition is hide the button if the Query Result is = commandArgument.

The error message is:-

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

-- string button = Button.CommandArgument**;

This is the Button

```
<asp:Button ID="addFollowerButton" runat="server" Text="Add as Follower" 
 CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProfileId") %>' OnClick="acceptRequest_Click" 
 CssClass="btn btn-info btn-xs pull-right" Width="135px" />
```

And this is the code

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // request Query string
        var querystring = Request.QueryString["ProjectId"];
        var Button = sender as Button;            
        string connectionString = 
       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

       string select = "Select ProfileId from Project_Follower Where ProjectId = @ProjectId";

       using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(select, myConnection);
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectId", querystring);

            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
            {
                string button = Button.CommandArgument;
                if (myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == button)
                {
                    Button hdn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("addFollowerButton");
                    hdn.Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: check my answer and tell me if helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first to find the button which is nested in the `ListView`

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{

      if(e.Item == null)
         return;

      Button btn1 = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("YourButtonID");
 }
```

For this to work you need to add specific ID for your button :

```
 <asp:Button ID="addFollowerButton" runat="server" ID="YourButtonID" Text="Add as Follower" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProfileId") %>' OnClick="acceptRequest_Click" CssClass="btn btn-info btn-xs pull-right" Width="135px" />
```

After you can do whatever you want with the button in the `ItemDataBound`. You can call:

```
btn1.Visible = false;//this will make the button not visible
string cmdArgument = btn1.CommandArgument;// this will take commandArgument of the button.
```

**EDIT:**

It should be `Button btn1 = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("YourButtonID");`

Comment: thanks, but the button already has an ID which is addFollowerButton

Comment: And i keep getting this error when i try to find the button. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @Jaco Yes I have an error it should be Button btn1 = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("YourButtonID"); Check it in the edit.

Comment: thank u very much, i can now hide the button, but i just need to figure out how to use it with a query. It works if ("1" == btn1.CommandArgument.ToString()), but doesnt work if if (myCommand.ExecuteScalar().ToString() == btn1.CommandArgument.ToString())

Comment: @Jaco If you have another question, ask it in new one. The policy of the site is to ask per one question. Create new one and someone will answer you.

Answer (score 0):

You're casting the `sender` object as `Button` in your code. But as you're doing this in the `ListView1_ItemDataBound`-eventhandler, the `sender` won't be of type `Button`. This results in a NULL-assignment to `var Button`.

Later in your code you're trying to get the `CommandArgument`-property of that `Button`-instance which gives you the NullReferenceException because the variable `Button` is NULL.

Maybe you can get the information about that button you want to hide from the `ListViewItemEventArgs`. Have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitemeventargs.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx